# Enable MSDTC WS-AT(Web Service Atomic Transactions) with SSL Certificate error

Tags: ssl-certificate, digital-signature, public-key-encryption, msdtc, wsat

I'm having an error trying to enable a SSL Certificate for the WS-AT module fot MSDTC:

I've already follow the steps to create the certificate:

[How to: Create and Install Temporary Client Certificates in WCF During Development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949057.aspx)

But still got this error:

"Could not use the SSL Certificate because it does not support Key Encipherment or Digital Signature"

I also made sure that I am using an admin accont and Application Data --> Microsoft --> Crypto -->RSA --> key file has the necessary full permissions to the admin account I am using

I'm using IIS 7, on a Windows 7 machine

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

I've made it work, finally. I've used the next commands

makecert.exe -pe -n CN=MyCN -cy authority -r -sv C:\Mycer.pvk C:\Mycer.cer

makecert.exe -ss Root -sr LocalMachine -n CN=MyCN -cy authority -r -sv C:\Mycer.pvk

makecert -ss My -sr LocalMachine -n CN=MyFullDomainName -sky exchange -ir LocalMachine -iv C:\Mycer.pvk -ic C:\Mycer.cer

hope it helps someone